# How to get button toggle state within HTML

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Angular 7 with Bootstrap 3.4.
This is a button toggle:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"
    autocomplete="off" (click)="onToggle()">
    {{<what to put here> ? 'On' : 'Off'}}
</button>
```

How do I fill the `<what to put here>` part in order to conditionally label my button according to its state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this part is condition of statement.
Think that isOpened  is boolean which is true then "On" will show else "Off" will show

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywyq51

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"
    autocomplete="off" (click)="onToggle()">
    {{ isOpened ? 'On' : 'Off'}}
</button>
```

but if you don't have any controls while changing condition then you can use it in your html without using function

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"
    autocomplete="off" (click)="isOpened=!isOpened>
    {{ isOpened ? 'On' : 'Off'}}
</button>
```

Comment: Maybe you can replace `(click)="onToggle()"` with `(click)="isOpened = !isOpened"` if there isn't any other login in the `onToggle()` function.

Comment: I did put in in stackblitz example. He may do some conditions in function so I didn't change it. But if there is no condition and only change situation, then u are true.

Comment: Data binding is a way  of course. I am wondering, since everything can be done with data binding, then why use 'data-toggle' and 'aria-pressed' in the first place?

Comment: @StefanosKargas Bootstrap uses its own JS files to interact with user events. It uses `data-` attributes to bind events. But since you are using Angular, you need to create variables inside your component TS file or local template variables to bind the data. Otherwise, how can Angular be aware of what is going on in the Bootstrap JS flow?

Comment: Or you can use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) to get Bootstrap components written in Angular.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a variable in your component such as,

```
isOn = false;
```

and in onToggle()

```
onToggle() {
  this.isOn = !this.isOn;
}
```

on the HTML template,

```
{{isOn ? 'On' : 'Off'}}
```

Comment: `!this.isOn;` does not return or modify any value. You need to assign `this.isOn = !this.isOn`

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, my mistake.